# How can we call fallback method of Hystrix in zeebe handler?

Tags: spring-boot, hystrix, zeebe

I have a service called payment-service which is down, and this is called inside a zeebe handler.Since the service is down it should call fallbackmethod of hystrix. But it is returning me success.

main class
[image]

controller class
[image]

delegate class
[image]

when I am executing localhost:8081/order-process it shows me success.
and in the console I get the error as
 I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8080/payment-service": Connection refused:

Please let me know why this fallback method is not getting called.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your REST service returns "success" is that you successfully started your job worker (https://docs.zeebe.io/basics/job-workers.html). The job worker then executing the jobs/service tasks from your BPMN processes.

Hystrix will be used WITHIN the handler to do the call, so a potential exception or default value needs to be taken into account WITHIN the handle method.